# Uploading Multipart Using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to upload a file (Audio File) to the server using Retrofit. 
But i am getting

> failure: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 8 path $

. though before, i used async tasks mutipartEntityBuilder and sent the file using httpPost successfuly. 
Here is the client side code i am using. if you need any more info (server side) i will post it.

thank you.

```
  @POST("/UploadImageFile")
    @Multipart
    void upload(@Part("file") TypedFile file,
                @Part("Name") String Name,
                @Part("Taskcode") String Taskcode,
                @Part("ClientId") String ClientId,
                @Part("Type") String Type,
                Callback<String> cb);

 RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
                .build();

        restAdapter.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
        RestAPI post = restAdapter.create(RestAPI.class);


        TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("multipart/form-data", new File(Path));
        String NameOfFile = typedFile.fileName();
        post.upload(typedFile,NameOfFile, currentTaskCode,HTTPRequestUserAuthentication.AppID,Type,new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void success(String s, Response response) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Success: "+s);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d(TAG,"failure: "+error.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: just to clear things out : are you sure youre using right path in @POST annotaion(because it's called UploadImageFile)

Comment: Yes its the right method:p..

Comment: I got this error now: failure: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 8 path $

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your problem, but are you sure about the MIME type of your `TypedFile`? I have successfully used this to upload a file: `new TypedFile("application/octet-stream", new File(postImageData.getFileName()))` - also in a `@Multipart` request.